# emacs: I need and explanation on dirtrack-list variable

Tags: emacs, emacs23

In emacs' shell I am using dirtrack-mode (`M-x dirtrack-mode`). I get errors in the `*Directory Tracking Log*` buffer:

> Input `user@machine:~/modules/mydir> ' failed to match `dirtrack-list'

In order to solve it I am trying to set the `dirtrack-list` variable to tell emacs the form of my prompt with no luck. This is mainly because I don't understand this variable's documentation:

> dirtrack-list's value is `("^emacs ^.\\{1,\\}@.\\{1,\\}:.+> " nil)`
>
> Automatically becomes buffer-local when set in any fashion.
>
> Documentation: List for directory tracking. First item is a regexp
>   that describes where to find the path in a prompt. Second is a number,
>   the regexp group to match.  Optional third item is whether the prompt
>   is multi-line.  If nil or omitted, prompt is assumed to be on a single
>   line.

Can anyone explain to me which is the *first*, the *second* and the third *item*?
How can I tell emacs which part of the prompt is the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of your `dirtrack-list` variable is a list:

```lisp
("^emacs ^.\\{1,\\}@.\\{1,\\}:.+> " nil)
```

This list consists of two items: a string and the symbol `nil`. The first item, as per the documentation, is a regular expression that is matched against your prompt to extract the path.

So, let's say your shell prompt looked like this:

```
toni@host [/home/toni/stuff] >
```

then you want the regular expression to match the part of the prompt that contains `/home/toni/stuff`. Obviously, the default regular expression for `dirtrack-list` does not do that, so you have to replace it. For the example above, something like this should do:

```
"^[^@]*@[^ ]* \\[\\([^]]*\\)\\] > "
```

In that regexp, the part that is the actual path is captured by the `"\\(...\\)"` group. Since it is the first (and only) group in your regexp, you want to put the number `1` as the second item of your `dirtrack-list` variable.

In order to use your own regexp like the one from the example, type <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `dirtrack-list` <kbd>RET</kbd>. Then edit the value to:

```lisp
("^[^@]*@[^ ]* \\[\\([^]]*\\)\\] > " 1)
```

and set it for the current session. Of course, you will have to use a regular expression that matches your actual prompt, not the one from my example.

Answer (score 2):

Thomas' answer was useful for me but the regular expression didn't work until I put in double backslashes.

For a prompt like:

`user@place:~/work$`

I set the dirtrack-list variable to

`("^[^:]+:\\([^\\$]+\\)\\$" 1)`

always using double backslash instead of single backslash.

[Backslashes must be entered as \\.](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression)

EDIT: Thanks to @phils for editing the original question and chosen answer to include doubled backslashes.

Below is the snippet added to my .emacs file to enable emacs 'dirtrack' mode - a mode where *shell* monitors the current directory by watching the prompt (assuming the pwd is printed in the prompt). The default mode 'shell-dirtrack' keeps track by parsing input commands for *cd, pushd*, and, *popd*.

I add it here as it is likely some readers of this page are pursuing that option.

```
(require 'dirtrack) ;change the method used to determine the current directory in a shell
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (shell-dirtrack-mode 0) ;stop the usual shell-dirtrack mode
            (setq dirtrack-list '("^[^:]+:\\([^\\$#]+\\)[\\$#]" 1)) 
            (dirtrack-debug-mode) ;this shows any change in directory that dirtrack mode sees
            (dirtrack-mode))) ;enable the more powerful dirtrack mode

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(dirtrack-list (quote ("^[^:]+:\\([^\\$#]+\\)[\\$#]" 1))))
```

You can see that *dirtrack-list* is set twice.  The first is locally in the shell mode hook.  The second is globally in a section automatically inserted when using the interactive UI command **M-x customize-variable [RET]** *dirtack-list* **[RET]**.  Probably only one is needed.

**Note**: the final regex covers two prompt cases:

`user@place:~/work$`

`user@place:~/work#`

**Note**:  Emacs has an interactive function **M-x re-builder** which makes testing for the right regexp very easy.

Comment: I've fixed those formatting issues in both the question and in Thomas' answer.